# PHP curl does not behave like command line curl if there are many redirects

Tags: php, curl

This is the file I want to download:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/minpspw/files/SDK%20%2B%20devpak/pspsdk%200.11.2/pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe
```

I can download it on the command line like this (please replace <URL>):

```
curl --output pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe -L <URL>
```

There are 4 redirects but at the end it saves a **32.6 MB file**. Now I try to do the same in PHP:

```
<?php 

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sourceforge.net/projects/minpspw/files/SDK%20%2B%20devpak/pspsdk%200.11.2/pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.jar");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.74.0"); // same as command line curl

file_put_contents("pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe", curl_exec($c));
curl_close($c);
```

But I only get an **HTML landing page** saying "Your download will start shortly..." (The landing page is written to file pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe).

As you can see in PHP I only get a landing page while command line curl downloads the actual exe file.

I tried to enable the referer, cookies and I've also set the user agent to the same as the command line curl.

How to fix my PHP code so it downloads the exe file and not only a landing page?

Comment: When you are using this download page in your browser, the _actual_ download of the file is not triggered by an HTTP redirect, but by `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=...">`. So I suppose somehow SF must think that your PHP cURL request was coming from a browser. You are f.e. using a cookie jar in your PHP cURL, that I don't see at all in your CLI cURL ...?

Comment: @CBroe Perhaps PHP curl doesn't support meta tag redirects? Removing the cookie jar line doesn't fix it.

Comment: _"Perhaps PHP curl doesn't support meta tag redirects?"_ - I doubt that command line cURL actually _does_. That SF somehow identifies your PHP cURL request as being "made by a browser", is more likely here, I think.

Comment: Try running your curl command with -v / --verbose to see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by disabling the referer header:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sourceforge.net/projects/minpspw/files/SDK%20%2B%20devpak/pspsdk%200.11.2/pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.85.0");

file_put_contents("pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe", curl_exec($c));
curl_close($c);
```

Comment: It works but setting those options is redundant: `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS`, `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`.

Comment: I think the default number of redirects is 5 so it might make sense to set it to something higher, user agent is also something you would like to set since some services rejects requests lacking this header. And, yes the cookie jar setting you can skip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, It directly downloads the file and store at the location where the script is stored.

```
$url = "https://sourceforge.net/projects/minpspw/files/SDK%20%2B%20devpak/pspsdk%200.11.2/pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe";
$local_file = "pspsdk-setup-0.11.2r3.exe";

$fp = fopen($local_file, 'w');

$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($c);

curl_close($c);
fclose($fp)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why? Keep in mind that there is already an accepted answer on this question, which means the OP has already solved their problem. An additional answer should contain some hints about why it should replace the accepted one

Comment: It works except there is a semicolon missing at the very end.